# Next JS data handeling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**_APP.JS**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  let primary = 'darkMode_Primary';
  let secondary = 'darkMode_Secondary'
  return (
    <Layout primary_super={primary} secondary_super={secondary}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

**LAYOUT.JS**

```
export default function Layout({ children , primary_super, secondary_super}) {

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar  primary={primary_super} secondary={secondary_super}/>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <ModeSwitch primary={primary_super} secondary={secondary_super}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

**NAVBAR.JS**

```
export default function Navbar(props) {

    const click = ()=>{
        console.log('USS')
    }

    const Primary = theme[props.primary]
    const Secondary = theme[props.secondary]
    return (
    <div className="NAV" id="NAV" style={Primary}>
        <div className="NAV_BOX_FULL NAV_LEX" style={Secondary}> 
            <img src="/NAV_img/cat.png" alt="" className="NAV_logo1 NAV_logo"/>
            <h3 className="NAV_head"  onClick={click} >SilenxIka</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

what i want to do is, when someone triggers that onClick fuction in navbar.js, the primary and secondary in _app.js

File style:
Navbar.js is inside of Layout.js and Layout.js is used in _app.js

Comment: Your question is not clear. what are you trying to achieve in onClick ?

Comment: You see that let primary and let secondary in _APP.JS? i want to change them dynamically on onClick

Answer (score 0):

In _app.js you can use state variables for `primary` and `secondary`.

like `const [primary,setPrimary] = useState('');` etc

Then define a `onClickHandler` function that would setState values for 'primary' and 'secondary'.
You can pass that function to Layout and attach it to `onClick`